# Another word for “ikigai”

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, translation

I read with interest an article by Dr. Sanjay Gupta about human longevity in Japan [on the CNN website.](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/11/12/health/ikigai-longevity-happiness-living-to-100-wisdom-project/index.html)

The main focus was on a word, and as so often happens in linguistics, also a
 concept:

***Ikigai***

> Ikigai has been drawn in books and articles as the center of a Venn diagram in which your answers to these questions all overlap:

•   What do you love?

•   What are you good at?

•   What can you be paid for?

•   What does the world need?

> When you find the answer that fits all four questions, that's your ikigai.
>   Another way of defining your own ikigai is to simply ask yourself: Why do you get up in the morning? Or, what motivates you?

Like anyone here, I would love to have a productive life beyond the 70s. So the meaning of ikigai is very interesting and relevant.

Is there a better word or phrase or idiom that expresses the idea beyond..

[**“purpose in life”**](https://www.success.com/what-is-my-purpose-in-life/)

Or

[**“*raison d'être*” “**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raison_d%27%C3%AAtre)

Comment: Presumably, the reason people use the term "ikigai" in English is because they think there isn't any existing English word that has the same meaning. But some similar words/phrases are given in the Venn diagram in the following post, which also mentions the Japanese word: [Difference between Vocation and Mission](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287985)

Comment: *Ikigai* (生き甲斐) simply means what you've already suggested, and an examination of the individual kanji yields not much more (Japanese words usually being more than the sum of their parts). I don't think there's anything in English that circumscribes the nexus of the four lobes of your Venn diagram exactly. Which may be why Gupta reached for the Japanese term.

Comment: A very nice English word (out of French) is **métier**, which the _American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2010) defines as follows: "**1.** An occupation, trade, or profession: ... **2.** Work or activity for which a person is particularly suited; one's specialty: ..." This more or less takes care of the "what do you love," "what are you good at," and "what can you be paid for" parts of the equation; but admittedly it doesn't address the "what the world needs" facet.

Comment: @Sven: Another French term suddenly comes to mind:  *raison d'être*.

Answer (score 2):

A person's **calling** in life - "a strong inner urge to follow an occupation, etc; vocation"

Source: [TheFreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/calling)

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately for us, concepts in Japanese tend to be expressed in compound words. As an example, the word in question here, *ikigai*, is a compound word, composed of these parts:

> **生き** - iki - living, being alive, vitality
>   **甲斐** - gai - worth, use, effect

As *ikigai* is a concept that pertains to one's *reason for living* we could take into consideration some of the literal meanings for iki and gai separately to understand that the possible more accurate translation is ***what gives your life worth***.